# c# csvhelper writing complex data

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I have the following object structure and trying to write to csv using csvhelper. but the filenames column in not getting added.

```
public class ClusterData
{
    public IEnumerable<string> FileName { get; set; }

    public int? ClusterNumber { get; set; }

    public string TopTerm { get; set; }
}


    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Clean.csv"))
    {
        var csv = new CsvWriter(writer);
        csv.WriteHeader<ClusterData>();
        foreach (var item in dataToCsv)
        {
            foreach (var filename in item.FileName)
            {
                csv.WriteField(filename);
                csv.WriteField(item.ClusterNumber);
                csv.WriteField(item.TopTerm);
                csv.NextRecord();
            }
        }
        writer.Flush();
    }
```

how to achieve with this?i want the outer loop to be repeated once and inner loop to be repeated for each item in filename.

Thanks

Comment: What do you expect to produce for `FileName`? It's not a *single* value so it can't be stored in a single column. Do you want to add N more columns, one for each file name? Concatenate all values into a single string? CsvHelper can't guess what you want to do here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the desired data and then use the writer to send it to file

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Clean.csv")) {
    var data = new List<ClusterData>();

    //...assuming data is poulated

    var dataToCsv = data.SelectMany(item => item.FileName.Select(filename => new {
        FileName = filename,
        ClusterNumber = item.ClusterNumber,
        TopTerm = item.TopTerm
    }));

    var csv = new CsvWriter(writer);
    csv.WriteRecords(dataToCsv);
}
```

A linq query is used to construct the desired object format for each file name in the data.

The data is then converted to CSV as it normally would using a `CsvWriter`